# Statusnet installation Issue

Tags: php, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, statusnet

I have been trying to deploy statusnet on Amazon EC2. I have set up the AMI and did other necessary things. Now when it comes to installation I get this error:

```
"No configuration file found.

I looked for configuration files in the following places:
/etc/statusnet/statusnet.php

/etc/statusnet/laconica.php

/etc/laconica/laconica.php

/etc/statusnet/ec2-174-XXXXXcompute-1.amazonaws.com.php

/etc/laconica/ec2-174-XXXXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com.php

/var/www/html/config.php


You may wish to run the installer to fix this.

Go to the installer."
```

When I click 'Go to the Installer" it shows the installation form but with this message above it:

```
"Cannot load required extension: gd

Cannot load required extension: xmlwriter

Cannot load required extension: dom "
```

Please help me to solve this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experiences in installing **StatusNet** on **Amazon EC2**, but I'd like give you some suggestions.

1. Copy the **htaccess.sample** file to **.htaccess** in your StatusNet directory and then change the "**RewriteBase**" in the new .htaccess file to be the **URL** path to your StatusNet installation on your server.
2. Modify the **php.ini** items related to **gd**, **xmlwriter** and **dom**.

Comment: Thanks for your response. :) Renaming htacess.sample wordked. The other other problemwas solved by installing xml and dom extensions. :)

Answer (score 0):

The PHP dependencies (extensions you need) are mentioned in [the text file named INSTALL](https://gitorious.org/statusnet/mainline/blobs/master/INSTALL) in the root directory of your installation.

Specifically:

- Curl. This is for fetching files by HTTP.
- XMLWriter. This is for formatting XML and HTML output.
- MySQL. For accessing the database.
- GD. For scaling down avatar images.
- mbstring. For handling Unicode (UTF-8) encoded strings.

Good luck!